# Pwm Pin continuously high

Tags: avr

I am trying to make a Phase and frequency correct pwm in Atmega 88pb. this is my pwm init method.

```
void PWM_INIT2()
{
DDRB|=(1<<PINB1) | (1<<PINB2);
TCCR1B |= (1<<WGM13) |  (1<<CS10);
TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1B0) | (1<<COM1B1) | (1<<COM1A1);
}
```

After adding it to my main my OCR1A pin keeps high always

```
int main(void)
{
  PWM_INIT2();

  while (1) 
  {
            
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
TCCR1B |= (1<<WGM13) |  (1<<CS10);
TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1B0) | (1<<COM1B1) | (1<<COM1A1);
```

You have set OC1A output to inverting, and OC1B to direct output, in mode 8 (PWM, Phase and Frequency correct) where the *TOP* value is defined by the content of register `ICR1`.

Therefore:

1. You have also to set some TOP value (which also defines the period duration of the timer), E.g.:

```
  ICR1 = 9999;
```

2. You need to set some output values in `OCR1A` and `OCR1B`:

```
  OCR1A = 1000;
  OCR1B = 5000;
```

Comment: i have set OC1A as inverting and OC1B to non inverting output. 
**1  0    Clear OC1A/OC1B on Compare Match when up-counting. Set
OC1A/OC1B on Compare Match when down-counting.

1  1   Set OC1A/OC1B on Compare Match when up-counting. Clear
OC1A/OC1B on Compare Match when down-counting.**

Comment: What if i Set ICR1 = 0;
                     OCR1A=0;
                     OCR1B=0;

Comment: if `ICR1 = 0; OCR1A = 0; OCR1B=0` then timer period will be 1 cycle, with output A constantly low, output B constantly high.

Comment: Then how do I bring both of the pins to low at the same time. It's confusing for me to understand so please elaborate.

Comment: Then you have to set non-inverted output to 0, and inverted output to a value higher than the period. E.g if you have `ICR1` set to 9999, then set `OCR1A = 0; OCR1B = 10000;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Now I am getting the out puts as I desired.. Really appreciable.

Comment: If this answer will help, it would be really nice if you accept it!